# check time and show grid containers flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Common Zone'),
  ),
  body: ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
    children: [
      SizedBox(height: 16),
      Text(
        'Common Zone - 20 Group Computers',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 16),
      GridView.count(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        mainAxisSpacing: 8,
        crossAxisSpacing: 8,
        childAspectRatio: 1.5,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: computers.map((computer) {
          bool isSelected = selectedComputers.contains(computer.id);
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => bookComputer(computer.id),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: computer.isBooked ? Colors.grey : isSelected ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  computer.isBooked ? 'Booked' : 'Computer ${computer.id}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: computer.isBooked ? Colors.white : isSelected ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
```

Im taking two time
start time
end time
it will book computer for particular time
but if computer is already booked by others than don't show that computer,
for that how can i check that from database.
in selected time computer is busy or not,
i tried my best to explain